# Time incorrect on Ubuntu and takes a long time to update

Tags: boot

Iḿ really satisfied with ubuntu, but for job necessities I need Windows too.

The problem for me appears when I change from ubuntu to windows7, the time is incorrect and take a lot of time to adjust itself using internet services.

---

Related with the time: Iĺl try to explain myself:

I am using linux, but meanwhile I need to use windows and I restart the system to boot into windows. Thereś no problem with this, but the time is incorrect.

That is:

When I am using linux, the time is correct, but if I restart to use windows, windows time is incorrect

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, is time incorrect in Ubuntu or windows? Both these OS's should fetch the time from the web.

Comment: What do you mean incorrect time? Off by exactly a multiple of hours? If so, then I guess you're running into a timezone issue where Windows stores the *local* time to the hardware clock and Linux stores UTC time there. Check this: [UbuntuTime](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime)

Comment: darkside - you appear to have two accounts - please click the link at the bottom of the page to merge your accounts.  The answer created by your second account has been deleted.  After merger - please add the information contained into your question.  Thanks.